# CkEditor5 File Upload error in Angular 16

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I'm trying to use the fileuploader plugin of ckeditor5 in angular 16, but it's giving me this error:

```
[ERROR] TS2322: Type 'typeof SimpleUploadAdapter' is not assignable to type 'string | PluginConstructor<Editor>'.
  Type 'typeof SimpleUploadAdapter' is not assignable to type 'PluginClassConstructor<Editor> & PluginStaticMembers<Editor>'.
    Type 'typeof SimpleUploadAdapter' is not assignable to type 'PluginClassConstructor<Editor>'.
      Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
```

Packages versions:

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^7.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core": "^39.0.2",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine": "^39.0.2",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload": "^39.0.2",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils": "^39.0.2",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-watchdog": "^39.0.2",
```

Some of my editor class:

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import {EditorConfig} from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core';
import '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/translations/de';
import {SimpleUploadAdapter} from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload';

export class TemplateFormComponent implements OnInit {
 Editor = ClassicEditor;
editorConfig: EditorConfig = {
    plugins:  [SimpleUploadAdapter],
    heading: {
      options: [
        {model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragrafo', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph'},
        {model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Titulo 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1'},
        {model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Titulo 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2'},
        {model: 'heading3', view: 'h3', title: 'Titulo 3', class: 'ck-heading_heading3'},
        {model: 'heading4', view: 'h4', title: 'Titulo 4', class: 'ck-heading_heading4'},
        {model: 'heading5', view: 'h5', title: 'Titulo 5', class: 'ck-heading_heading5'},
        {model: 'heading6', view: 'h6', title: 'Titulo 6', class: 'ck-heading_heading6'}
      ]
    },
    language: 'pt'
  };

...

onReady(editor: any) {
    this.editTemp= editor;
    this.model = editor.model
  }
}
```

html:

```
<ckeditor id="txtid" [config]="editorConfig" [editor]="Editor" formControlName="text" (ready)="onReady($event)" (change)="changeText($event)" style=" max-width: 650px; border:var(--ck-focus-ring); border-color:#ced4da;"></ckeditor>
```